# How to set initial value for read only field

Tags: django-1.6

I have a django application which is using `django.contrib.admin` for administrative tasks.

For one model I now need to add a field which indicates which part of the code each row was created from. I am using `readonly_fields` to prevent this value from being changed through the administration interface.

A default value in this field will tell me that the row was either

- created before the field was introduced
- created by code which has not been updated to set the field
- created through the administration interface

But I need better granularity than that. In particular I want to be able to distinguish between a row created by code which doesn't know about the field, and a row created through the administration interface.

Is there some way my `ModelAdmin` class can specify an initial value for a field mentioned in `readonly_fields`?

Comment: is there a constructor?  That's where you can set it most other languages.

Comment: @Mark I could add a constructor to the class, but how would the constructor know whether it was called from `django.contrib.admin` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, which appears to work:

```py
class Admin(ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('created_by',)
    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        r = super(Admin, self).save_form(request, form, change)
        if not change:
            assert r.created_by == CREATED_BY_UNKNOWN
            r.created_by = CREATED_BY_ADMIN
        return r
```

`CREATED_BY_UNKNOWN` and `CREATED_BY_ADMIN` are values defined elsewhere in my code.

Comment: It might be slightly better to override `save_model`, as this seems to be the [documented approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: @JoshuaPokotilow It's been 1½ years, and I no longer remember exactly which approaches I tried before coming up with my solution. So I cannot tell you whether using `save_model` was tested and discarded for some reason. I can tell you that the solution I came up with worked, and to the best of my knowledge it is still being used and never caused a problem.

Comment: I don't doubt your approach works. Just pointing out an alternative that might be more future-proof. I don't see `save_form` documented anywhere, so there's a possibility (however remote) that Django will stop calling it someday. Unless something has been peculiarly customized, there's also no reason to think `save_model` wouldn't work just as well as `save_form` for Django 1.6 or later, at least given the stated problem / proposed solution.

Comment: @JoshuaPokotilow Sure. I'll keep your suggestion in mind in case I ever need to do anything similar again. The code base in question was tested with 1.8 and there were many other things which did not work. So it surely would be a significant undertaking to port it to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is,

```
def get_form(self, request, caja=None, **kwargs):
    self.form = YourModelForm

    form = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, caja, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['field'].initial = your_initial_data
    return form
```