# Django Admin Form: Set the default value of a readonly field

Tags: python, django

THE GOAL: Display a *request-specific*, read-only `user_id` on a django admin form when creating and updating a resource.

This display should be a readonly field (*readonly*, NOT disabled). The `user_id` displayed is derived from the requesting user (`request.user`) so the initial value is set from that.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604306/how-to-assign-initial-value-to-a-custom-fields-in-modeladmin), we should simply set it in the `get_form` method like so:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
    form = super(ProfileAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['user'].initial = request.user
    return form
```

However, user is no longer on the `base_fields` when it is readonly. In fact, I can't find it anywhere. Any thoughts?

[Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796938/how-to-set-initial-value-for-read-only-field) suggest on save, which I intend to do, but I need it to show on the form before then.

Comment: Is the user field present in your model ?

Comment: As a relation, yes... could that help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right that making the field **readonly** excludes it from the `base_fields`.As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) :

> Any fields in this option (which should be a list or tuple) will display its data as-is and non-editable; they are also excluded from the ModelForm used for creating and editing.

You could have define a method for it just like `list_display` but since you need to set user from the request, we need to have the request object, which isn't available in the method.

So for your use case, we can use [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method as :

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'lend_by':
        # setting the user from the request object
        kwargs['initial'] = request.user.id
        # making the field readonly
        kwargs['disabled'] = True
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The field will still have add/change buttons. To remove these, we can extend `formfield_for_dbfield` (which calls `formfield_for_foreignkey`). It may also make sense to move the code above into that same method, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54197083), to have it all in one place.

Comment: This doesn't work when create a new record since the `disabled` attribute makes the value of the field to be ignored when the form is submitted.